# How can we sync data between Amazon dynamo database and Relational database

Tags: relational-database, amazon-dynamodb, data-synchronization, bidirectional-relation

We are planing to develop an application with Amazon Dynamo db. Actually this application is collecting information from my client's database(my client's are using MYSQL, Oracle,MSsql/ any other Relational database), doing some process in my application and send back results to the client's database. This synchronization process should work always(or every 1 minute interval).

I want to know is there any tools(or tricks) are available for synchronization between Amazon dynamo database and Relational database?

Answer (score 2):

You can consider Elastic Map Reduce job, which reads from dynamo, transforms the data and writes back to relational database. (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/EMRforDynamoDB.html)

Edit: Also look at Data Pipeline (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-taskrunner-rdssecurity.html)